# How to make a process always be called when schedule() executed in Android?

Tags: android, linux, schedule

My platform is Android, and my code is a C program which runs on user space. This program will read spi data, which has a corresponding spi kernel driver.
In the driver, it makes a kernel thread, which runs a while(1) loop like below.

```
while(1)
{
    spi_sync();  // read 5KB data
    write_data_to_ram();
    msleep(4);
}
```

And my system HZ=1000, that means the schedule() will happen each 1ms. The while(1) loop runs about every 10ms (spi_sync() and write_data_to_ram() spend 6ms) as we measured by oscilloscope, and we hope it could always be like that.

But in fact, sometimes (quite rarely) the loop will run for 20ms or even 100ms long. That means when schedule() happens, our process is not called.

I use nice(-20) function and sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param) to make my process to be RT process and owns worst nice value. Then theoretically my process should always be called firstly when schedule() happens, right? But still it will run like 100ms long, although quite rarely.
Why?

Is it possible to make my process be called always 10ms long? Or in another word, each 10ms when schedule() happens, my process will be called first, how?